# Question on Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the only holomorphic (differentiable) function $f$  of the form $ f(x +iy)=u(x)+iv(y)$ is given by $f(z)=λz+a$  for some $λ\in R$ and $a\in C$.

Differentiable means its satisfies C-R equations. i.e., $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.   here i structed.

Can any one help.  thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer the following questions and then you should be able to answer the question you have posted.

$(1)$. Is $\dfrac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x}$ a function of $y$?

$(2)$. Is $\dfrac{\partial v(y)}{\partial y}$ a function of $x$?

$(3)$. If a function of $x$ equals another function of $y$, when is this possible?

$(4)$. Use one half of the Cauchy-Riemann equation, i.e., $\dfrac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial v(y)}{\partial y}$ and $(3)$(above) to conclude that $u(x)$ is an affine function in $x$ of the form $\lambda x+a_1$ and $v(y)$ is an affine function in $y$ of the form $\lambda y+a_2$.

$(5)$. Conclude that $f(z) = \lambda z+a$

Answer (score 0):

By taking limits along each axis, we get $f'(x+iy) = \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v(y)}{\partial y}$. The only way this can be true is if  $f'(x+iy)$ is a real constant, call it $\lambda$. Hence we have $f(z) = f(0) + \int_0^1 f'(tz) zdt = f(0)+\lambda z$. Setting $a=f(0)$ gives the desired result.