# Exercise about holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $f:\mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such that $\exists a,b:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x+iy)=a(x)+ib(y)$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $\exists \lambda,k \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=\lambda z+k$ .

I tried to use the condition given by the Wirtinger derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=f'(z) \qquad \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=0
$$
And the fact that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}
$$
and the same for $\partial y$, but this only gave me $f'(z)=2a'(x)$, which seems not going anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried writing down the cauchy riemann equations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question on Complex Analysis.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365262/question-on-complex-analysis)

Comment: @KennyWong the problem is that $a,b$ are complex valued, so it is not clear to me why they would equal the real part and the imaginary part of $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really has been given by @Kenny Wong and others, but I'll spell it out a bit more:

Because $f$ is holomorphic the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied:
$$
a_x = b_y, \quad a_y = -b_x = 0
$$
Since $b_y$ is not a function of $x$ it follows that $a_x$ is not a function of $x$. Similarly as $a_x$ is not a function of $y$ it follows $b_y$ is not a function of $y$.
Hence, there are constants $c,d,f \in \mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align}
a_x &= c \Rightarrow a(x) = cx + d \\
b_y &= c \Rightarrow b(y) = cy + f
\end{align}
So
$$
f(z) = a(x) + ib(y) = cz + k, \quad k = d+if
$$

Comment: I understand your solution, but the thing that bothers me is that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are related to $\Re f, \Im f$, while $a,b$ are complex valued a priori, so we cannot say that $a=\Re f$ and $b=\Im f$. Maybe there is a typo in the text of the exercise?

Comment: @LuigiTraino Yes I think there could be a typo for otherwise it doesn't make much sense to write $f = a + ib$.